# php bind_param forbidden

Tags: php

Preciso fazer o `insert` do conteúdo feito no editor [summernote](https://summernote.org/).

Só que o `bind_param` esta bloqueando porque o editor gera conteúdo html. Exemplo:

```
<p style="text-align: center; "><b>Titulo</b></p>
```

Ai quando faço o submit, aparece essa mensagem:

Erro: **Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /arquivo.php**.

Como permitir que o `bind_param` permita a inserção?

**Meu código:**

```
if ((isset($_POST["form"])) && ($_POST['form'] == "form1")) {
  $rs = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contratos (nomeContrato, texto, dataModificado) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");

  $rs->bind_param('sss',
    $_POST['nomeContrato'],
    $_POST['texto'],
    $_POST['dataModificado']
    );

  $rs->execute();


  if ($rs->errno) {
    echo 'Erro: ', $rs->error;
  } else {
    echo "<script>window.location='sucesso.php'</script>";
  }
}
```

Comment: O que te faz achar que é o `bind_param` que está bloqueando o acesso ao arquivo?

Comment: Porque quando envio texto sem nenhuma formatação o `insert` funciona.

Comment: Consegue ver no arquivo de log ou `mysqli_error` se deu algum erro específico?

Comment: Eu uso `ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_erros',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` E não aparece nada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se não falhe a memoria, existe uma função que modifica tags para que sejam enviadas ao mysql, mas não lembro o nome. Se me lembro bem ela coloca uma barra invertida ````\```` para anular o codigo.

Comment: Tiago, o nome dessa função é `htmlentities`