# Trocar tags html antes do insert php

Tags: php

Estou criando uma função para que seja trocado as tags html ao fazer o insert, e depois quando for recuperar.

Estou fazendo corretamente?

CLASS

```
class handle
{
  public static function removeTag($target)
  {
    $output = preg_replace("#{~#", "<", $target);
    $output = preg_replace("#~}#", ">", $target);
    $output = preg_replace("#{{q}}#", '"', $target);
    return $output;
 }

  public static function colocaTag($target)
  {
    $output = preg_replace("<", "#{~#", $target);
    $output = preg_replace(">", "#~}#", $target);
    $output = preg_replace('"', "#{{q}}#", $target);
    return $output;
 }
}
```

Ao enviar para o banco de dados:

```
$comTag = '<p class="important-text">Meu texto com tag </p>';
handle::removeTag($comTag);
```

Chegaria assim no sql

> {~p class={{q}}important-text{{q}}~}Meu texto sem tag {~/p~}

Recuperando no echo:

```
$SemTag = '{~p class={{q}}important-text{{q}}~}Meu texto sem tag {~/p~}';
echo handle::colocaTag($SemTag );
```

> `<p class="important-text">Meu texto com tag </p>`

To no caminho certo?

Comment: Talvez isso possa influenciar em algo, então por que precisa fazer isso? Há alguma limitação/problema em guardar o HTML no banco?

Comment: Uma ideia é, em vez de usar HTML, guarde no banco um markdown, depois transforme o markdown em HTML no frontend com JS

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A ideia é aumentar a proteção.

Comment: Proteção contra o que?

Comment: @Costamilam markdow, não tinha ouvido falar sobre esse termo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Expressei errado, não é proteção é que o `bind_param` está bloqueando inserções com tags, então pretendo fazer algo para que ele funcione.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397903/php-bind-param-forbidden

Comment: Já se certificou que o problema realmente é entre o `bind_param` e o valor em HTML?

Comment: Você usa ele o tempo todo no **StackOverflow** (<= isso é um markdown)